# Internal storage in non-context area

Tags: android, kotlin

I think it's just a basic question but I used to face the problem from different view. It concerns internal storage or any other method of saving data under android dev.

As far I used to dance with qt cpp/c#/dx9 gaming/etc, but what hit me at android development is that context and disinformation. As usual I wanted to decouple the code a bit, this time I decided to swap fragments in one activity, which got me pain in the ass in form of back button control.

Then I thought to myself, let the model control data retrival and save (viewmodel whatever), and i hit the shit. I've lost the context, so I can't simply get current dir, file locations from .io without passing activity/fragment to model class.

Anyone could tell me what are the methods of retriving data (as dummy content is made, but there is static crap) ? Let it be sync or async, anyway, I want my model to play here and there, what I see is that I hit the wall of missing context because of decoupling. I think I started the wrong way but i can't find the right track.

The main figure here is that I want to use internal storage and sync it with external DB later. The good example of what i'm going to achieve is to render the recycler view and give the app the way to swap it with another view, so i need one clean data model.

Comment: IMHO, model objects should not be involved in disk I/O, any more than they should be involved in network I/O. Repositories can handle the I/O, with the model objects remaining Android-free (see the "Clean Architecture" pattern). And a repository can hold a reference to an `Application` context (e.g., supplied by dependency injection).

Answer (score 0):

Well yeah, I've seen repos as a form of data retrival. I'll retrack the idea and thank you for answer. As we call model (c++ struct) as data only then in fact, data shouldn't load itself, I just wanted to make a shortcut as it's just basic model. On the other end, many web frameworks tend to use models as data factories/loaders, here's my wild concern.